# How to kill a program run inside screen that is not responding?

Tags: linux, display, python, kill

When running a python program inside a screen, from time to time the program stucks right from the beginning after just starting it and I can't quit it using Ctrl+C. (^C will be typed but no response). The behaviour is, as far as I can tell, totally non-deterministic and occurred on very rare occasions. The program in question is implemented in Pytorch but don't think the problem is cause by a bug in the program.

So far this happened on three occasions. On the first two I tried to quit from inside the screen using Ctrl+A and typing `:quit` and/or by trying to kill the python program using `kill` / `kill -9`. After using `kill -9` the program went into zombie mode and we had to reboot the server since it was blocking GPU memory and using 100% CPU.

This time when it happened I prefered to come here and ask how this should be handled properly. Curiously the program is not occupying any GPU space as `nvidia-smi` shows (which is rather weird in on itself). But the program still uses 100% CPU as `top` shows.

`pstree` gives this:

```
systemd─┬
        ├─screen───python─┬─{python}
                          └─{python}
```

Is there a solution that would properly kill the program and how can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Have you tried running the program  outside of screen?

Comment: Yes and there wasn't any problem with that, only I let it run inside the screen to be able to log off and let it run in the background. Note that the exact same program runs most of the time without any problem inside screen, this behavior occurred only on 3 occasions out of a couple of dozens of runs.